# Get request 404 on asp net web application owin

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, owin

I have simple asp.net web application on .net framework 4.7.2

It has one simple controllers

```
    public class ServiceApiController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string ping()
        {
            return "pong";
        }


    }
```

and has a startup class

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")
            {
                SupportsCredentials = true
            };

            cors.Methods.Add("POST");
            cors.Methods.Add("GET");

            config.EnableCors(cors);
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ServiceApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}"
            );
            IoCCommon.Start(typeof(Startup).Assembly, config);

            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

when hosting locally via VS 2019 and IIS Express, I send request with Postman on address: http://localhost:8055/ServiceApi/ping

and I receive response "pong"

but when I host this application on a remote machine on IIS and send request on: 
http://machine-address:8055/ServiceApi/ping

I get response "404 - File or directory not found."

Do you have nay suggestions what the problem might be?

**Update:**

On machine when I go to link (Internet Explorer) http://localhost:8055/ServiceApi/ping

I get same error: 404 not found

Comment: "when I host this application on a remote machine on IIS" is vague. You have to reveal how you did that and how IIS configuration there looks like. Even the tiniest mistake, such as wrong site bindings, can lead to 404 as the requests can be routed to another site, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the way of hosting the project.
OWIN defines an abstraction between the DotNet web server and web application. OWIN decouples the web application from the server, which makes OWIN ideal for self-hosting a web application in your own process, outside of IIS.
In a word, when using OWIN to host the application, there is no need to use a web server(IIS). IIS will provide a service base address by using website binding, which will make the base address of OWIN unavailable. However, when hosted locally, the service address is provided by the application itself, this is commonly completed by the `Application_start()` method of the `Global.asax`

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            //host OWIN with below address.
            var _webapplication = WebApp.Start(url: "http://localhost:9203");
        }
```

Here is an example of self-hosting the WebAPI in a console application, which is similar to my description of self-hosting WebAPI project.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.